# Configuring Eclipse Content Assist for UIMA Ruta scripts

Tags: eclipse, uima, ruta

Is it possible to configure Eclipse such that when editing `.ruta` files (Ruta scripts), the Content Assist feature works?

By default, when I try to induce the tool to give me help with `Ctrl` + `(space)` and *without typing anything*, I get an error (I will reproduce it shortly) that suggests I edit the "Other Scripts" settings in the "Content Assist" settings - roughly speaking.

Unfortunately, I cannot find anything like "Ruta Content Assist" in my Eclipse preferences.

Now, if I do type some stuff in, and hit the hotkey, I will usually get results if my prefix is valid.

For instance, if I type:

`IMPORT PACKAGE * FROM`

...and hit `Ctrl` + `(space)`, I get an error.

[image: Error]

But if I type:

`IMPORT PACKAGE * FROM org.`

...and hit `Ctrl` + `(space)`, I get a list of suggestions from `Uima` packages.

[image: NoError]

Comment: could you document the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

The error dialog is caused by a bug. Most probably, an element of the AST of the IDE editor is null causing a null pointer exception, which terminates the content assistant process.

The observation with the prefix is caused by a limitation of the UIMA Ruta Workbench. However, the proposals in your example are also wrong, because they contain types but should contain type system descriptors.

Overall, the problems are caused by bugs and limitations of the internal AST.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta (and I will fix the bugs)*